# C# implementation of Levenberg–Marquardt algorithm

Tags: c#, least-squares, levenberg-marquardt

I am looking for a C# implementation of the [Levenberg–Marquardt algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm) for non-linear least squares fit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Levenberg-Marquardt.NET by Krzysztof Kniaz](http://kniaz.net/software/LMA.aspx) has worked very well for me.

Comment: Thanks! I had a look at it a while ago, I couldnt get it to work when I had several input and output parameters for each data point.

Comment: Thanks! I had a look at it a while ago, I couldnt get it to work when I had several input and output parameters for each data point. Basically I have 3-D input coordinates and 3-D output coordinates, and 3-D reference coordinates for each data point. The 12 parameter function is supposed to make the output equal to the reference value for each point. Thus I calculate the norm of the error (reference value - output value) for each data point in the set as the function I want to minimize. I wasnt able to rewrite the code so that it achieved this.

Comment: Instead I use a robust c++ program and a c++ to c# wrapper function.

Comment: Sorry that library did not work for you but good to hear you found a way to do it. Do you mind sharing which C++ library you used? Have you considered trying to port it to C#? Not worth the effort or are you concerned about speed?

Comment: http://joachimwuttke.de/lmfit/index.html the library is in c. the quick and dirty solution i did was to compile the source code as a c++ project, and create a dll that could be executed from c#, using DllExport() / DllImport()

Comment: I moved the lmfit repository to http://apps.jcns.fz-juelich.de/lmfit.

Comment: http://apps.jcns.fz-juelich.de/src/lmfit/lmfit-6.1.tgz

Answer (score 6):

You might want to try [csmpfit](http://csmpfit.codeplex.com/). It is open source.

**Update:**

The project has been moved to GitHub at https://github.com/cureos/csmpfit.

Comment: This one is really easy and works flawlessly

Answer (score 2):

Here is an explanation article plus C# code:

http://www.imagingshop.com/articles/least-squares

It uses Math.NET Numerics for linear algebra to simplify the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm.